# Hibernate: EmbeddedId with auto increment

Tags: java, database, hibernate, jpa, type-safety

Suppose that I have a simple Hibernate entity with auto-incremented id.

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "product")
public class Product {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private String name;
}
```

Is it possible to declare `id` as a type-safe variable? I could apply `@EmbeddedId` like this.

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "product")
public class Product {
    @EmbeddedId
    private ProductId id;

    private String name;
    
    @Embeddable
    public static class ProductId implements Serializable {
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
        private Long id;

        public Long getId() {
            return id;
        }
    }
}
```

It works with client-generated IDs, but not with database-generated ones.

Has anyone solved similar problem? What are the possible approaches?

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to annotate ProductId class with @Embeddable like this:

```
@Embeddable
public static class ProductId implements Serializable {
    private Long id;
    private String name;
}
```

And, when you save entity, you need to create an instance of ProductId with unique parameters (in your case it is "name" field) as well.

For more information, I suggest you to have a look at [here](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-jpa-embedded-method-parameters)

Comment: I forgot to put `@Embeddable` annotation. Fixed that. Anyway, that's not answering my question. I do understand that I can instantiate `ProductId` directly. But I want to have an advantage of `@GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)` annotation usage. How can I combine it with `@EmbeddedId`? I want to deal with `ProductId` in my code but now with `Long` raw type.

Comment: Because they define entity uniquely together, I believe you can not do this. But there is a workaround you may find it useful in here https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#identifiers-composite-generated